# How to make a vector that contain all possibilities of characters

Tags: r

I want to make a vector which contains all possibilities of specific characters in selected length. For example, characters are `A`, `B`, `M`, and selected length are two, then the output should be `AA, AB, AM, BA, BB, BM, MA, MB, MM`.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following approach which would give all the possible combinations of 2-Letters from the given list of letters.

```
do.call(paste0,expand.grid(rep(list(c('A', 'B', 'M')), 2)))
# [1] "AA" "BA" "MA" "AB" "BB" "MB" "AM" "BM" "MM"
```

Comment: Perfectly solve my problem thank u so much

Comment: Sorry, I forget to tick it. Thank you again : )